# Is it possible to access an android phone web server from outside lan

Tags: android, networking, ip, webserver, lan

Situation: I have an app on my android phone that allows me to setup a basic web server from my phone, which i would like to access through the browser on our school computer. My laptop and phone are connected to the same WiFi at home, which allows me to access the server using my phone's lan ip and the service's port number (which i assign to 50000).

However our school computers use a wired lan (ethernet) which can't be changed, although a school WiFi is available for students. I can connect to this WiFi through my phone, however I'm not sure how to access my phone (and the server) from the school computers which are inside the wired lan. I know my phone's public ip, but as i'm not an administrator port forwarding on the routers is not an option.

Is it possible to achieve this connection for free without any additional hardware?, or simply impossible?, any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the setup of the firewalls of your school’s network and whether devices connected to the Wi-Fi can access the rest of the network - generally network administrators would section off a public/guest Wi-Fi from the rest of the network for security.

First thing to check would be to find the internal IP address of your phone when connected to your school Wi-Fi, try to then browse to the address of your website using that IP.  If it doesn't work, try to ping your phone's IP from a networked pc and see if you get a response.  If none of that works, chances are its blocked by a firewall (as it should be).

In order to get it to work, you probably need to connect your phone to the same VLAN as the networked pc's (without and Ethernet Port), if you can find a networked pc with a Wi-Fi chip you could configure it as a hotspot and connect your phone to that.  This would put your phone on the same VLAN as other networked pc's.